# Recode by not using conditional

Tags: javascript, typescript

The below function works good by if statements , I want the same functionality by using without condition statements.

```
Hello(x){
    If(x<0){
       Console.log("greater");
    }Else{
       Console.log("smaller");
    }
};

Hello(1);
Hello(-1);
```

Comment: Would a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) do? It's still a condition though. I don't think it's possible without a condition of some kind

Comment: *"I want the same functionality by using without condition statements."* Why?

Comment: `return ['greater', 'smaller'][+(x < 0)];`.

Comment: @Teemu  magic

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Object but it's odd. An [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement or it's shorter [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) form more clearly conveys the logic at play which is always preferable.

```js
function Hello(x) {
  const lt = {
    true: "smaller",
    false: "greater"
  };

  console.log(lt[x < 0]);
};

Hello(1);
Hello(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a stupid thing to actually do and might be overly specific to your example but...:

```js
const hello = (x) => {
  const lt = x < 0;
  console.log("greater".repeat(lt) + "smaller".repeat(1 - lt));
};

hello(-1);
hello(1);
```

Borrowing from @Teemu's comment a slightly more flexible thing could be:

```js
const if_else = (cond_fn, if_fn, else_fn = (x) => x) =>
  [else_fn, if_fn][+cond_fn()]();

const hello = (x) =>
  if_else(
    () => x < 0,
    () => console.log('greater'),
    () => console.log('smaller')
  );

hello(-1);
hello(1);
```

Comment: lol. I think you can safely take 'probably' out of that sentence ;)

Comment: @pilchard I part remember seeing a video once by someone who was explaining that removing conditionals can speed up code by eliminating the need for branch prediction or something like that. (This was compiled code hmmm ... possibly assembly actually (I didn't understand much of it)). Anyway, this was with numbers, and based on a true or false result part of the equation was multiplied by 0 or 1 thus not requiring branch prediction. This was the first idea I came up with for strings. :)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm amused by solution. Also it's not that far off my object suggestion so we're in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

@Teemu explained how to do it without **branching**, and there are times where that can be beneficial (example: [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array/11237235#11237235)).

```js
function hello(x) {
  console.log(['greater', 'smaller'][+(x < 0)]);
}

hello(1);
hello(-1);
```

but by definition you cannot achieve behavior based on a condition without a **conditional**.